# Tibco ems integration with JMS

Tags: java, sms, jms, tibco-ems

I am badly struggling to integrate Tibco EMS in Java. If anybody have experience, please advice me to do it. I did following  coding but i don't know to continue next step.

```
Context jndiContext = null;
ConnectionFactory cFactory = null;
Connection conn = null;
Session session = null;
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://10.6.136.141:8222");
jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);
cFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("FTQueueConnectionFactory");
conn = cFactory.createConnection("loyalty", "loyalty");
session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Comment: Do you need to use JNDI ? If not you can just create the com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory(). Otherwise, what's your error message ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to setup JNDI if you do not need it. Simply use the TibjmsConnectionFactory class:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:7222");
connection = factory.createConnection(userName, password);
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
destination = session.createQueue(name);
```